# Difference between .create() and .createWithMixins() in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

What is the difference between `.create()` and `.createWithMixins()`? I am not able to find any documentation regarding this. When I create a view instance using `.create()` and call `this._super()` in the `didInsertElement` method then,  following error is thrown:

> Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call
>   _super.

But, when I replace `.create()` with `.createWithMixins()` everything works fine. Here is the code and the sample js fiddle :

```
App.SampleView = Ember.View.create({
    sampleProperty : "a",
    didInsertElement : function(){
        this._super();
        this.set("sampleProperty", "b");        
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bErRT/3/.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin):

> In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class, which
>   contains a combination of methods from other classes. How such
>   combination is done depends on language, but it is not by inheritance.
>   If a combination contains all methods of combined classes it is
>   equivalent to multiple inheritance.

In Ember instances of objects are created with the `create` method with no arguments, or with a single hash(kvo) that represent the properties of that type, and they will be automatically populated. Example:

```
var SomeClass = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: '',
    url: ''
});

// this instance will have a "name" and a "url" properties with blank values
var someInstance = SomeClass.create();

// this instance will have the same properties, but now 
// their values will be populated
var anotherInstance = SomeClass.create({
    name: 'Ember.js',
    url: 'http://emberjs.com'
})
```

On the other hand, `crateWithMixins`, allow you to *mix* another class definition into a single object instance or into another class. So let's say you have the same `SomeClass` above, but you don't want to sub-class it via `extend` and create another type. In this case you can use a `Mixin` to make sure that only that one instance will have that definition of the two classes. Example:

```
var SomeClass = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: '',
    url: ''
});

// note that you don't extend a mixin, you only create
var SomeOtherClass = Ember.Mixin.create({
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log('doing my thing');
    }
});

// This instance will have a method called "doSomething"
var x = SomeClass.createWithMixins(SomeOtherClass, { 
    name: 'Ember.js', 
    url: 'http://emberjs.com' 
});

// this instance only has methods/properties defined in "SomeClass"
// therefore, no method called "doSomething"
var y = SomeClass.create({ 
    name: 'Google', 
    url: 'http://google.ca'
});
```

However, if you want to create a new class with a `Mixin`, you can `extend` `Em.Object`, passing the `Mixin` as the first argument, as follows:

```
var AnotherClass = Ember.Object.extend(SomeOtherClass, {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: ''
});

var z = AnotherClass.create();
z.set('firstName', 'Hiro');
z.set('lastName', 'Nakamura');
z.doSomething();
```

Check out the [**API Documentation**](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) as well as this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/xuHTV/).

**Edit**: As for `_super()`, you only use this when you create a new class (via `extend`). When you `create` instances of existing classes, you shouldn't call `_super()`.

Another thing. I see you're trying to `create` a `View` directly. I believe, based on your code, you should be extending `Ember.View` and let the framework create instance for your at the appropriate time. If you create manually, you'll be responsible for some parts of its workflow like appending it to the DOM, removing it, etc. Maybe I don't see the whole picture, but based on this code alone, I think you should *not* call `create` there and call `extend` instead, and then you'll be able to call `_super()`

Comment: @Joe, Thanks a lot for this elaborate explanation. It was indeed very helpful for me. If we should not use .super() during instance creation, then why ember does not throw any error if I use the its minified version?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the minified version strips out a few assertions. Usually the debug/development version has all assertions to help you identify potential issues while the minified is for production use, so it assumes you're done testing.