# this._super() issue when an object is created

Tags: ember.js

In the new EmberRC1 version, it seems that we cannot call super class method from a created object. I have some standard mixins and views which i use to either create or extend to some other objects. I have some methods overriden, but still i needed to execute super methods which we can acheive in previous versions using `this._super()`. But in the newer version, when i create an object, this is not happening.

```
    window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("users");
});

App.UsersView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    init : function(){
        this._super();
        this.pushObject(App.TestView.create({
            didInsertElement : function() {
               this.$().append(' <br><h4>Appended at Object</h4> ');
            }
        }))
    }
});

App.TestView=Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'test',
    didInsertElement : function() {
       this.$().append(' <br><h4>Appended at Class</h4> ');
    }
});
```

So is this part completely removed or we can acheive this super calling some other way?

To understand my problem here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/TaWAU/9/).

**PS:** I know that i can have the code that needs to be executed with some other methodname and call the same method. But it would be nice if i have solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can still call this._super() from an init method and it will call the parent. What has been removed is calling create on an object and passing in an init method. There is a createWithMixin method that still allows that functionality.

There is a pretty detailed post about this functionality here:

[Difference between .create() and .createWithMixins() in ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091828/difference-between-create-and-createwithmixins-in-ember)