# adding class properties without reopenClass

Tags: ember.js

I was just wondering if it is possible to add class properties inside a class definition in Ember.js?

i.e. inside `Ember.Object.extend`, rather than inside a separate `Myclass.reopenClass`

Things I put in extend are only accessible in instances.

Comment: You can use [Ember.Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html). More on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091828/difference-between-create-and-createwithmixins-in-ember/15092868#15092868)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at that, thanks